# HTML table align cells with header from another table

Tags: php, html, css

I think there is a simple way to align these table cells with the header from another table.

I tried to set the width of every table cell to 6%, this this doesn't align them completely.

This is my table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVzFC.jpg

This is how I create the table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered turnover_list">
    <thead>
        <tr class="sorting_1">
            <th>Company</th>    
            <th>Year</th>

            <?php

                if($_POST['selectall'] == 0) {
                    $allCompanies = array();
                    $allCompanies[0] = getCompanyName($_POST['company']);
                    $allCompanies[1] = getCompanyName($_POST['compare']);
                }

                if($_POST['frommonth'] != "" && $_POST['tomonth'] != "" && $_POST['fromyear'] != "" && $_POST['toyear'] != "") {
                    $fromMonth = $_POST['frommonth'];
                    $toMonth = $_POST['tomonth'];
                    $fromYear = $_POST['fromyear'];
                    $toYear = $_POST['toyear'];
                } else {
                    $fromMonth = 0;
                    $toMonth = 11;
                    $fromYear = date('Y');
                    $toYear = date('Y');
                }

                for($i=$fromMonth; $i<=$toMonth; $i++) {
                    echo "<th>" . $months[$i] . "</th>";

                    array_push($selectedMonths, $months[$i]);
                }

                for($i=$fromYear; $i<=$toYear; $i++) {
                    array_push($selectedYears, $i);
                }

            ?>

            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php

        foreach($selectedYears as $year) {

            $turnoverTotal = 0;

            echo "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered turnover_list'>";
            echo "<tbody>";

            $monthTotal = array("January"=>"0", "February"=>"0", "March"=>"0", "April"=>"0", "May"=>"0", "June"=>"0", "July"=>"0", "August"=>"0", "September"=>"0", "October"=>"0", "November"=>"0", "December"=>"0");

            foreach ($allCompanies as $companyName) {

                $companyTurnoverTotal = 0;

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style=''>" . $companyName . "</td>";
                echo "<td style=''>" . $year . "</td>";

                foreach ($selectedMonths as $month) {
                    $sql = "SELECT SUM(mob + www) AS 'turnover' FROM turnover WHERE year = '" . $year . "' AND companyID = '" . getCompanyID($companyName) . "' AND month = '" . $month . "'";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
                    $companyTurnoverMonth = $row['turnover'];

                    $monthTotal[$month] += $companyTurnoverMonth;

                    $companyTurnoverTotal += $companyTurnoverMonth;

                    echo "<td style=''>" . make_format($companyTurnoverMonth) . "</td>";
                }

                $turnoverTotal += $companyTurnoverTotal;

                echo "<td style=' font-weight: bold; background-color:#d3d3d3;'>" . make_format($companyTurnoverTotal) . "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }

            echo "<tr style='font-weight: bold;'>";
            echo "<td style='background-color:#d3d3d3;'>Total</td>";
            echo "<td style='background-color:#d3d3d3;'>" . $year . "</td>";

            foreach($selectedMonths as $month) {
                echo "<td style='background-color:#d3d3d3;'>" . make_format($monthTotal[$month]) . "</td>";
            }

            echo "<td style='background-color:#d3d3d3;'>" . make_format($turnoverTotal) . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            echo "</tbody>";
            echo "</table>";
        }

    ?>

</table>
```

I created a separate table header, because the user is able to compare companies.

Is there a way to create a table header with multiple other tables (without header) underneath it and have it all aligned with the table header?

This would be my desired result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0s23.jpg

Comment: Why not only one table with empty row ?

Comment: PHP is of little use to us. We'd need **actual** HTML/CSS tables in a demo

Comment: Can I make a live demo with database data?

Comment: @Core972, do you mean just <tr></tr> ?

Comment: Yes something like `<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>` could do the trick ?

Comment: @Core972 This will create a border on the sides of the empty row